# accept commands and call the methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which contain different methods.

now I want my main() acts as a REPL. I have different commands each refers to a different method. (eg. command1(call method1) )

I want to print a prompt as >>>
and accept one command at a time then call the method

how can I do this?

```
    class supermarket(object):
            def __init__(self):
                    pass
            def method1(self):
                    pass
            def method2(self):
                    pass
            ...

    def main():
```

by the way, i am using python 3.5

Comment: it seems like `argparse` is a good choice for you。 this tutorial might helpful https://pymotw.com/2/argparse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getattr()` function to fetch attributes by name, then just call the resulting method object:

```
def main():
    s = supermarket()
    while 1:
        cmd = input('>>> ')  # or raw_input('>>> ') if using Python < 3
        if cmd in ('q', 'quit'):
            break
        print(getattr(s, cmd)())
```

if the method names are different from the commands you'll need some way to translate (and then there is no need to use `getattr`):

```
def main():
    s = supermarket()
    while 1:
        cmd = input('>>> ')
        if cmd in ('q', 'quit'):
            break
        print({
            'command1': s.method1,
            'command2': s.method2,
            # ...
        }[cmd]())
```

Comment: what does this line "if cmd in ('q', 'quit'):" mean?

Comment: If the user enters either `q` or `quit` then we break out of the `while 1` loop. It's a clean way to exit.

Comment: You put `:` at end of `cmd = line` by mistake and also change `raw_input` to `input` since the answer should be for python 3.X. Didn't know `getattr`, thank you!

Comment: I don't know what your methods do, but if they return a value you can print the result of the method call (answer updated)

Comment: @thebjorn just one more thing, if my command has different name from my method, how can I use getattr in this case?  Shall I call the method directly?  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle the case where command and method names are different.